# Correct Method: Scale emprical CDF or best fit CDF

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

I have some data, with max value $M$. I assume it is sampled from some distribution with infinite support. A best-fit CDF is calculated $F(y)$ and so is an empirical CDF $F_{N}(y)$.

My issue is that $1-F_{N}(M)=0$ whereas $1-F(M)>0$. My solution is to simply let 
$F_{N}(y)=F_{N}(y)\times F(M)$. Is this best practice? The other option would be to let $F(y)=F(y)/F(M)$ so that all the weight is before $M$.

Why I care: I'm going to do some p-value analysis to determine whether the hypothesis of the data being drawn from the assumed distribution is plausible and so the empirical CDF and best-fit CDF have to be as close as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The [K-S test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) doesn't worry that $F_N(M)=1$ and, as a goodness-of-fit test, seems to be what you're looking for.  If that and similar tests are no good then could you tell us a bit more about the problem you're trying to solve?